# SVN: Force to checkout file?

Tags: svn

Recently some of my files have stopped showing as being modified in SVN even though they are. `svn status` just shows nothing modified. Not all files are being ignored though. Seemed to happen randomly.

Is there an easy way to force  it to double check the files to notice there were changes made?

What even causes this issue?

Comment: Can you do a checkout of the affected tree in another local directory (ie: checkout a separate working copy) to ensure the files are still present? The most common case of such issues is the `.svn` folders being clobbered/deleted/corrupted, and the SVN client no longer recognizing the path as part of a local working copy.

Comment: You say "checkout file" in your question title. Is that significant? Are you actually trying to do a "update" or "checkout", or are you actually just trying to view your working copy locally changed files state.

Comment: Trying to get SVN to noticed local changes I have done to some files. I never could figure out the cause and ended up deleting the entire svn folder and re-downloaded the files from the server. Fixed the issue. Just trying to keep that from happening again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the command line version of the Subversion client or TortoiseSVN? Sometimes, TortoiseSVN icons don't necessarily show accurately.

If you're using the command line, you can use the `svn status -v <fileName>` command. This will show you the status of the file whether or not it has been modified or *ignored*. The status is shown in the first column. A blank entry means that the file is in Subversion, but not modified. A `I` means the file is not in Subversion, but is being ignored (this is something you setup). A `M` is modified, an `A` is added and `D` is deleted.

The verbose setting will show you the revision checked out, the last changed revision, who made the last change, and the file's name.

If you're using TortoiseSVN, you are given the option to install the command line client. I always recommend users to do that.

---

## I'm not using TortoiseSVN

Okay, I am assuming that if files are missing, it is possible that a checkout was done as a *sparse checkout*. Or, files were added, but are not yet showing up in your working directory. In that case, do an `svn update`. This will update the file to the latest revision, and if the file had been added since the last checkout, will add that file to your working directory. This is probably close to the *force checkout* you're talking about. You can also specity the `--set-depth` setting to override the possible *sparse checkout*. Using it never hurts:

```
$ svn update --set-depth=infinity
```

This will update everything to the latest version, and make sure ***everything*** is checked out in your working copy. This will update files that you've modified, but will try not to change the lines that you've modified.

Comment: I am just using command line. Good to know. I will try this 'svn update --set-depth=infinity' next time I have this issue.

Comment: I had another set of files do the same thing today. Some .scss files were not showing being modified even though I was working in them all day. I manually copied them over to save my hours of work. Then ran `$ svn update --set-depth=infinity`. Any changes I then made to them were then showing up as the file was modified. Thanks again!